# Django : pre selection or tags. model relations

Tags: django, django-models, database-design, django-rest-framework, database-relations

**Django Version is 2.1.7**

Hello, i have a OneToMany Relation and i ask my self if there is a possibility to make some kind of pre-selection (Tags or so?) for my Farmers? 
Because not every Farmer has or wants Chickens or he is specialist in Cows only.
Means, right now, whenever i want to assign an individual Animal to a Farmer, i see all Farmers displayed in my Django Admin. With a growing Number of Farmers it gets confusing. So i thought to insert some Kind of Model Field in my `Farmers` Model... like `chickens = true or not true` and `cows = true or not true` or to introduce a new model for every species.

My Goal is, to assign a set of species to a every farmer. So that the Next time i want to add a chicken django shows only Farmers that will work with Chickens on their Farmland, it makes no sense to Display all Farmers, when some Farmers know that they handel only a specific set of species.

As a Newbie i would guess i have to make some new models for every Species with a ManyToMany Relation? So `Farmers` **><** `Species X, Y, Z` < `Indiviual Anmial`.

Thanks

```
class Farmers(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
farm_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='farm/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
slug_farm = models.SlugField(blank=True)

<...>

class Chickens(models.Model):
farmer = models.ForeignKey(Farmers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
chickenname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

<...>

class Cows(models.Model):
farmer = models.ForeignKey(Farmers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
cowname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

<...>

class Rabbits(models.Model):
farmer = models.ForeignKey(Farmers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
cowname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

<...>
```

Comment: Can a farmer have chickens , cows and others both. Or a farmer who work with chicken only will work with chicken ?

Comment: Both. Farmer A has Chickens, Cows and Rabbits. Farmer B has Cows and Rabbits. Farmer C has Cows and Chicken. So next time i add a chicken i like to see only Farmer A and B as a possible data assignment choice in my django admin.

Comment: If all farmers  will be pre-polulated before assigning them animal or then can be added in run time. Lets say when we add a new farmer D what will happen ?

Comment: i guess i would set a default value to every species. Farmer D: would pre-polulated with no species. Therefore no animals. I mean i could add choices to my Farmer model (Chickens, Cows, Rabbits, Default=No Species) and then maybe add a query to my admin. "If adding Chicken only show Farmers with Choice Chicken". But in my case there are multiple Choices at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If we are using `postgres` as DB then `arrayField`[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) 
can be a good option for doing this job.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Farmers(models.Model):
   .... necessary fields

    SAMPLE_CHOICES = (
        ('CHICKEN', 'CHICKEN'),
        ('COW, 'COW'),
        ('No Species', 'No Species')
        .....
    )
    choices = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(choices=SAMPLE_CHOICES, max_length=10, blank=True, default='No Species'),
    )
```

Now whenever we need to filter on `Farmer` model based on choices we can do this like following

```
Farmer.objects.filter(choices__contains=['cow'])
```

#### Update

As you are using django-mysql database, following thing by `django-mysql` [link](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) here we can have field feature like `ListField` [link](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/list_fields.html#list-fields) and can easily achieve this.

Comment: i am using the regular Django Database its MySQL. But i will look into Postgres in some time, but first i need to understand the basics in Django. Thanks.

Comment: @black_hole_sun then we can try `django-mysql` which provide additional model field like `JSONField` or `ListField` both should able to do your require work. I have updated my answer with additional link, hope this will help you. Thank you for your appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ChickenFarmers(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
farm_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='farm/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
slug_farm = models.SlugField(blank=True)

class CowFarmers(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
farm_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='farm/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
slug_farm = models.SlugField(blank=True)

class RabbitsFarmers(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
farm_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='farm/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
slug_farm = models.SlugField(blank=True)

class Chickens(models.Model):
farmer = models.ForeignKey(ChickenFarmers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
chickenname = models.CharField(max_length=100)



class Cows(models.Model):
farmer = models.ForeignKey(CowFarmers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
cowname = models.CharField(max_length=100)



class Rabbits(models.Model):
farmer = models.ForeignKey(RabbitsFarmers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
cowname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

'''
I think at this point this will give you best relief
'''